# How do I check my Electret mic?

Tags: amplifier, microphone

I recently soldered an electret mic. I have never soldered before. How do
I check whether I have damaged the electret mic? If it was a speaker I could have done continuity check but for a mic I don't know. I measured the resistance it comes somewhere around 1.7Kohm. If I blow into mic ,it
comes to 2Kohm. Is this how we check it?

[image]

I made a pre-amplifier circuit. It's not working. I am not sure whether it is the problem with the mic or the circuit.

Comment: 2MOhm seems too much. What the datasheet says?

Comment: It doesn't come with a datasheet

Comment: Hard to believe it's alive. What is your amplifier circuit?

Comment: sorry- there is a typo, it's 2KOhm.

Comment: Then it's just fine, the circuit is bad.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum:  http://easy-electronics4u.blogspot.in/2012/01/simple-one-transistor-microphone.html

Comment: Check polarity. The mic has plus and minus

Comment: I don't get any voltage difference in the output capacitor using DMM. I checked the polarity it's fine.

Comment: It's fine, you can't see it with dmm.

Comment: Speaker should give some output right?

Comment: Depends. I don't see it on scheme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electret mics have a built-in FET as an "amplifier" which requires power.

- get a power supply, say 5V
- connect GND to the - of the mic
- connect 5V to a 22k resistor, the other side of the resistor goes to the mic
- connect your oscilloscope between GND and the + pin of the mic
- start whistling, alter two frequencies
- change input sensitivity on the scope, you shall see a signal in millivolts range
- and you will see nice sine waves as you're whistling.

Basically this is what you do (without the output capacitor, which cuts the DC power from the output):

http://i0.wp.com/www.scienceprog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Electret_condenser_microphone_schematic.jpg?resize=300%2C208